# lightning-record-edit-form rich text field issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, richtextarea, lightning-inputfield

When we pass value from `<lightning:textarea>` (Aura Component) to LWC's `<lightning-input-field field-name={fieldNameWhichisRichTextField}>`. If i send any value that starts with symbol '<' example: `<add/>` That value is not coming in `<lightning-input-field field-name={fieldNameWhichisRichTextField}>` its empty. If i remove '<' then the values comes properly in lighnting-input-field. Why data is not getting passed from `<lightning:textarea>` to `<lightning-input-field field-name={fieldNameWhichisRichTextField}>`  when there is '<' symbol ?

Note: This works fine if value from `<lightning:textarea>` passed to a `<lightning-input-field field-name={fieldNameWhichisText}>` only for richtextarea values are not coming

Comment: Did you try to HTML encode the value?